# SVN Checkout for deploying Maven projects

Tags: java, svn, tomcat, maven

I have a Maven Spring MVC project. How do I add that to a SVN and perform commits and how do I deploy it to a Tomcat server via SVN checkout. I have created an account with assembla. what's the next step?

Currently I use `mvn war:war` command to build war for deployment. But its a tedious job as for a small change we may have to deploy all the files again.

Or do you suggest any other method for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out, compile, test, build, report and deploy. That's a job for [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Jenkins. In DEV, if you run a Tomcat server locally, you can create a symbolic link from your src/main/webapp folder into the deploy folder (the linked should have .war suffix).

To have all libs (and other required configured resources) automatically injected in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF, run
`mvn war:inplace`
(make sure you do no commit those resources to SVN)

A dummy edit to web.xml will trigger an automatic re-deploy in Tomcat (not true in Jetty)